# Received server error (500) from primary and could not load the entire response body from endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 442, in lambda_handler
    pred_prob = invoke_endpoint_with_idx(endpointname = ENDPOINT_NAME, target_id = transaction_id, subgraph_dict = subgraph_dict, n_feats = transaction_embed_value_dict)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 314, in invoke_endpoint_with_idx
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpointname,
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 508, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 911, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

[image]

I got the above error while running [realtime-fraud-detection-with-gnn-on-dgl/src/sagemaker at main · awslabs/realtime-fraud-detection-with-gnn-on-dgl · GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/realtime-fraud-detection-with-gnn-on-dgl/tree/main/src/sagemaker).

Once shouted the endpoint and called it from Lambda and received that error. I redid it several times but it's always the same error. Can you help me please?

Comment: What size is the input data? If it’s several megabytes, you may be hitting an HTTP size limit imposed by Lambda?